# How to reduce memory footprint of V8 Isolates?

Tags: javascript, v8, webassembly, emscripten, isolate

I have a C++ application using the V8 library that runs JavaScript+WASM code (say, `xyz.js`) generated by Emscripten compiler. If I run an infinite loop (`for (;;) {}`) in V8 and measure memory footprint of each additional isolate running in its own thread, it comes to be around 1.1 MiB.

However, if I run `xyz.js`, the memory footprint is around 40 MiB. The JavaScript part of `xyz.js` is around 200 KiB, and the WASM part (encoded in base64) is around 800 KiB. It doesn't seem normal for such small code to compile into dozens of megabytes.

The C++ code is very similar to the [V8 Hello World sample](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/branch-heads/11.9/samples/hello-world.cc) with minor refactoring.

Is there any way to reduce the memory footprint of Isolates? I tried disabling the JIT but that also disabled WASM support.

Comment: V8 will pre-malloc the space it needs to manage the stack and heap. This is an optimisation because a memory pool is usually faster than calling malloc. I personally haven't quite found a way to trim this apart form deliberately spawning fewer threads

Comment: Where to save memory depends on where it's being used. How have you measured "memory footprint"? Why do you think the memory is used for code? How big is the Wasm module's memory? How big is the managed heap? If the latter is large, what's on it?

Comment: @jmrk The 60 MB is reported as the PSS. Massif only reports around 4 MB. WASM module is about 800 KB. I'm not sure how to get the data of "managed heap".

Comment: I didn't mean the size of the Wasm module (which you stated in the question), I meant the size of the Wasm memory that this module allocates when it's instantiated and/or used (Wasm memories can grow, if the module wants them to). You can easily inspect the managed heap if you run your app in Chrome (or another browser) and take a heap snapshot; supporting the DevTools protocol in your own app is possible too but is more work, see https://v8.dev/docs/inspector.

Comment: As a general principle, the size of JS source or Wasm modules doesn't have much to do with the memory consumption when executing them. For example, `var a = []; for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) a[i] = new Array(256000);` is 68 bytes of JS that takes ~1GiB when run in Chrome (or ~2 GiB in Node.js, due to lack of pointer compression). You could construct similar examples in Wasm.

Comment: I think that it is the emscripten-produced code WASM that pre-allocates a heap and a stack, not V8 itself

Comment: @Criminal_Affair_At_SO Any idea how to go about disabling that? I tried to use [these flags](https://emscripten.org/docs/tools_reference/settings_reference.html?highlight=initial_memory#initial-memory) but it didn't have any impact.